# What is the .ssh/config corresponding option for ssh -N

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-config

I am trying to set up an alias in my config that should give the same result as

```
ssh -N -L 3307:1.1.1.1:3306 username@remoteip
```

My current .ssh/config looks something like this.

```
Host connect
    User username
    HostName remoteip
    port 22
    LocalForward 3307 1.1.1.1:3306
```

What do I put in the above config to not start a shell?

```
Host connect
    User username
    HostName remoteip
    port 22
    LocalForward 3307 1.1.1.1:3306
    SessionType none
```

sessiontype just gives Bad configuration option: sessiontype even though its documented on [manual for ssh](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html) options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of SSH are you using (`ssh -V`)?

From the [release notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7) it looks like this feature was only added in version 8.7 released in August last year. Maybe updating SSH might solve your problem?

Comment: For clarity, the `SessionType` option is new, while the `-N` flag has been there for a while.  You are likely to have a version of ssh that supports `-N` but not `SessionType`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @drlim2u. I didn't realize I needed to update my ssh, 8.4p1 is from 24 Aug 2021, but that date was just when the security patch was applied.  8.4 is from 2019.